# Why do I get file permission errors when updating Homebrew when installing does not require any such permissions?

Tags: macos, homebrew, file-permissions

I have a mac running Catalina (all updates installed).

I have installed homebrew using the command given on https://brew.sh/

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

It does not ask me for superuser privileges when installing.

When I try to update homebrew it fails saying my user needs permissions to certain folders. In my browsing, I read somewhere that brew does not need elevated permissions, then why does an update require permissions?

```
Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/share/man/man5
/usr/local/share/man/man7

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7
```

I also tried the `brew doctor` which again says that I need to give my user, permissions to the above two folders but then there is a note there that says.

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/share/man/man5
/usr/local/share/man/man7
```

**So my questions really is, is it OK to change these file permissions? and why does a brew update require change to the file permissions but not an install?** I ask because I don't want to get into a permissions mess for some other software. (I had to reformat my mac to come out of the mess). I am also thinking about statements like **'You don't need sudo to install npm'** etc... I guess my question is a classic case of FUD.